# GPU accelerated SHA256 calculation under Linux or Windows?

Tags: gpu, sha-2

I am curious whether or not there is a way to calculate the SHA256 sum of some file faster than the CPU does on GPU.

Note that I am **NOT** interested in *cracking* anything.
I don't care about password attacks or any other kind of attacks.

All I wanna know is:

- is there a way to compute the SHA256 sum of a given file on a GPU?
- is it faster than on the CPU compared to standard tools (openssl, sha256sum, hashalot, mhash, ...)?

The way I understood the highly hyped hashcat tool it hasn't even support for calculating the cryptographic hashes of any files, apparantly it only operates under "attack modes" using in-memory data hashing and simply cannot use files as sources (or maybe because it's not faster than a CPU then, IDK).

So essentially I wanna know: Is there a way to hash faster on my PC having a good Nvidia GPU?

If the answer is a definitive *NO*, then that's also good - so I can just stop looking further.

Comment: Yes;  You can calculate a SHA256 hash with CUDA.  If you can't find a tool that does this, you would have to make one yourself, there is code out there to calculate the SHA256 hash so it shouldn't be hard.  Look into the enormous world of BitCoins, entire "industry" built on calculating SHA256 hashes were formed.

Comment: Maybe this thesis can help: https://fenix.tecnico.ulisboa.pt/downloadFile/395145839854/Resumo.pdf